# What is the difference between sichah biteilah and devarim yeserim?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, speech-talking

On Shabbos one should refrain from speaking about mundane matters. The Rambam makes a statement that one should refrain from sichah biteilah on Shabbos (Hilchos Shabbos 24:4) while the Rosh uses the phrase devarim yeserim (Shabbos 15:2). What exactly is the difference between the two statements? Are these just two statements saying the same thing or is it possible that devarim yeserim also includes how much one speaks?

Comment: I went ahead and added sources and cleaned up your grammar for you. In the future would you please try to do that before posting? Thanks!

Comment: I don’t think the amount is the difference, because even the Rambam writes “lehabos bisichah biteilah,” to increase in unnecessary speech. Perhaps the difference is in quality instead?

Comment: @DonielF I think it would make sense that they would both agree on quality in terms of refraining from devarim b'teilim. My question is more on the rosh and perhaps in addition to the quality he holds the quantity should be less on shabbos?

Comment: I should note the Shulchan Aruch OC 307:1 uses the Rambam’s wording.

Comment: Literally, we have _devarim yeserim_: talking more than necessary (going on about your latest _thing_ in excruciating detail, though even saying Gut  Shabbos was frowned upon, apparently), and _sichah biteilah_: talking nonsense (like analyzing the latest polls for next year's elections, maybe).